# When file from volume in the docker-compose becomes available in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have docker-compose file looking similar to:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  my_service:
    build:  
      context: ./my_service
    ports:
      - $SERVICE_HTTP_PORT:1234
    volumes:
      - $PATH_TO_FILE:/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/root.ca.crt
```

Then inside docker file I have following line:
`RUN chmod 644 /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/root.ca.crt && update-ca-certificates`

but that yields that there is no such file. As far as I understand that probably it is not available at that moment yet, but couldn't find any documentation for that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing to docker volume from Dockerfile does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25982460/writing-to-docker-volume-from-dockerfile-does-not-work)

Answer (score 1):

As volumes are not part of the generated image itself, you cannot write to them in a Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

you have to write that command into the docker-compose file instead

```
command: bash -c "chmod 644 /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/root.ca.crt && update-ca-certificates"
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - what makes you think that this command resolves the problem that volumes can not be bound during building the image?

Comment: my_service_1  | chmod: cannot access '&&': No such file or directory
my_service_1  | chmod: cannot access 'update-ca-certificates': No such file or directory

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev oops sorry I didn't add bash -c "..." . I guess it is fixed now

Comment: If I do like that then container exists after this command `my_service_1  | Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d... $$$ my_service_1  | done. $$$ platform_my_service_1 exited with code 0` ($$$ == new line)