# Gradle docker image: can't create files in the .gradle directory

Tags: docker, gradle, dockerfile

I want to build my project using Gradle docker image. Since I need to feed it proper repository URL and credentials, I decided to output them into `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`, just like you usually do it locally on your machine.
However I am stuck on an issue of not being able to create any files inside `~/.gradle`.

Here's a sample Dockerfile:

```dockerfile
FROM gradle:8.5-jdk21-alpine

RUN ls -la .
RUN echo hello > out
RUN ls -la .
WORKDIR .gradle
RUN ls -la .
RUN echo world > out
RUN ls -la .
```

Which gives the following output:

```
Step 1/8 : FROM gradle:8.5-jdk21-alpine
 ---> 5d527d32c7be
Step 2/8 : RUN ls -la .
 ---> Running in 5195db2c8c4f
total 12
drwxr-srwx    1 gradle   gradle        4096 Jan 27 08:42 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jan 27 08:42 ..
drwxr-srwx    2 gradle   gradle        4096 Jan 27 08:42 .gradle
 ---> Removed intermediate container 5195db2c8c4f
 ---> 18666307c9c5
Step 3/8 : RUN echo hello > out
 ---> Running in b7f9dfb48848
 ---> Removed intermediate container b7f9dfb48848
 ---> 0dded2505644
Step 4/8 : RUN ls -la .
 ---> Running in 7c7342768fd0
total 16
drwxr-srwx    1 gradle   gradle        4096 Feb  9 17:02 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Jan 27 08:42 ..
drwxr-srwx    2 gradle   gradle        4096 Jan 27 08:42 .gradle
-rw-r--r--    1 root     gradle           6 Feb  9 17:02 out
 ---> Removed intermediate container 7c7342768fd0
 ---> a50b7ebba4f3
Step 5/8 : WORKDIR .gradle
 ---> Running in d2fc92439198
 ---> Removed intermediate container d2fc92439198
 ---> 1537b03de558
Step 6/8 : RUN ls -la .
 ---> Running in 68e6257e2cc3
total 8
drwxr-srwx    2 gradle   gradle        4096 Jan 27 08:42 .
drwxr-srwx    1 gradle   gradle        4096 Feb  9 17:02 ..
 ---> Removed intermediate container 68e6257e2cc3
 ---> 9ac58a7ff572
Step 7/8 : RUN echo world > out
 ---> Running in 41543dabd95f
 ---> Removed intermediate container 41543dabd95f
 ---> ca7b08f161fc
Step 8/8 : RUN ls -la .
 ---> Running in 27d1c45d32b6
total 8
drwxr-srwx    2 gradle   gradle        4096 Jan 27 08:42 .
drwxr-srwx    1 gradle   gradle        4096 Feb  9 17:02 ..
 ---> Removed intermediate container 27d1c45d32b6
 ---> a7ef272b3325
```

Why does this happen? Does this folder have some kind of special handling? Why are no errors raised? Is there a more idiomatic way to feed repository credentials to a gradle container?

**EDIT:** Found out from gradle dockerfile sources that this directory is acatually an anonymous volume mount. I tried changing group ownership of `/var/lib/docker` to group `docker`, which my user is part of, but that didn't help either.

Comment: "try" `USER gradle` as the second dockerfile instruction.

Comment: @xerx593 unfortunately, that didn't help

Comment: sorry, i cannot reproduce with the OP dockerfile! (`--progress=plain`;)

Comment: "Is there a more idiomatic way to feed repository credentials to a gradle container?" -> https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out why this was happening with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25984380/5999354). Volume changes are thrown away after every step, which can be verified by modifying the `echo` command to also include `ls` in the same line:

```dockerfile
FROM gradle:8.5-jdk21-alpine

RUN ls -la .
RUN echo hello > out
RUN ls -la .
WORKDIR .gradle
RUN ls -la .
RUN echo world > out; ls -la .;
RUN ls -la .
```

This gives the following output:

```
Step 1/8 : FROM gradle:8.5-jdk21-alpine
 ---> 5d527d32c7be
Step 2/8 : RUN ls -la .
 ---> Running in 1d99342cfce8
total 12
drwxrwsrwx    1 gradle   ping          4096 Jan 27 08:42 .
drwxrwxr-x    1 root     ping          4096 Jan 27 08:42 ..
drwxrwsrwx    2 gradle   ping          4096 Jan 27 08:42 .gradle
 ---> Removed intermediate container 1d99342cfce8
 ---> 0c77d08c8085
Step 3/8 : RUN echo hello > out
 ---> Running in c64200a76484
 ---> Removed intermediate container c64200a76484
 ---> a29955cb9ff5
Step 4/8 : RUN ls -la .
 ---> Running in 7af67fd34245
total 16
drwxrwsrwx    1 gradle   ping          4096 Feb 17 07:03 .
drwxrwxr-x    1 root     ping          4096 Jan 27 08:42 ..
drwxrwsrwx    2 gradle   ping          4096 Jan 27 08:42 .gradle
-rw-r--r--    1 root     ping             6 Feb 17 07:03 out
 ---> Removed intermediate container 7af67fd34245
 ---> e5099e079c8b
Step 5/8 : WORKDIR .gradle
 ---> Running in 021a47532a8b
 ---> Removed intermediate container 021a47532a8b
 ---> 00d4b7be91d9
Step 6/8 : RUN ls -la .
 ---> Running in e40f3c04e52b
total 8
drwxrwsrwx    2 gradle   ping          4096 Jan 27 08:42 .
drwxrwsrwx    1 gradle   ping          4096 Feb 17 07:03 ..
 ---> Removed intermediate container e40f3c04e52b
 ---> 7623abe1f032
Step 7/8 : RUN echo world > out; ls -la .;
 ---> Running in 82ad883884a6
total 12
drwxrwsrwx    2 gradle   ping          4096 Feb 17 07:03 .
drwxrwsrwx    1 gradle   ping          4096 Feb 17 07:03 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root     ping             6 Feb 17 07:03 out
 ---> Removed intermediate container 82ad883884a6
 ---> a01a29be26cb
Step 8/8 : RUN ls -la .
 ---> Running in 04675a6228fc
total 8
drwxrwsrwx    2 gradle   ping          4096 Jan 27 08:42 .
drwxrwsrwx    1 gradle   ping          4096 Feb 17 07:03 ..
 ---> Removed intermediate container 04675a6228fc
 ---> 72a7145007f5
```

Evidently, the file does exist, but only at that specific step.

As for my use case, I'll probably end up simply creating `gradle.properties` in the project directory instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this is the best way to feed this information into your Docker image, but here's something that does what I believe you want.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM gradle:8.5-jdk21-alpine

COPY gradle.properties .gradle/gradle.properties
# These commands are just to validate that the file is there.
RUN ls .gradle
RUN cat .gradle/gradle.properties
```

That assumes that you have a `gradle.properties` file in your local directory, which is then being copied across into `.gradle/` on the image.

Other options for sharing this information with your image would be:

- just use a project-level `gradle.properties` file;
- using a volume mount to share a `gradle.properties` file from the host with a running container; or
- pass in these settings as environment variables.

For the purpose of illustration I created a `gradle.properties` with the following content:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```

[image]

In Step 3/4 you can see that the file is indeed in the `.gradle` folder and in Step 4/4 you can see that the content of the file on the image is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I actually decided to do it this way because in the end this dockerfile would be run on a Gitlab server, and I was wary about dumping credentials into the shell. For the same reason I can't really keep them inside the project (cause it would have to be under VC), and volume mounting seemed like a fairly complicated setup, since the Gitlab server is not under my direct control.

What puzzles me is that I can copy files into this directory (which turned out to be a volume mount), but cannot do anything with it using `RUN` directives.

Comment: If you're using GitLab then another option would be to use environment variables, which you can set up in your CI configuration.

Comment: Also, if you're happy with my answer then please accept it. Thank you.